# Maps with Geopandas: Shapefile coordinates are in millions

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I am trying to plot data on a shapefile with geopandas but the shapefile has coordinates in the millions: so for example the coordinate (30, 30) is (3000000, 3000000). Naively, I am just thinking that the separator somehow wasn't read when using gpd.read_file(). This of course causes the maps to not line up as seen in the image. Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this?

[Geopandas plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLL6t.png)

Comment: Maybe the shapefile is just using a different CRS (coordinate reference system) from your base map?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you might be using something else than the the standard/default EPSG:4326 coordinate system (CRS). When loading geometry data to GeoPandas you have to specify the CRS. You can change this afterwards via GeoPandas' to_csr() function. The wanted CRS depends on your location of interest.